# how to prevent two similar charactors occur together anywhere in a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to prevent two similar characters for example "@" to occur anywhere in my string.
how i can  do that .this is my string:

```
    static string email = " example@gmail.com";
```

Comment: what do you mean "prevent"?

Comment: the string does not accept the characters.

Answer (score 2):

In case of answer of Moo-Juice, you can use Linq in CounOf extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int CountOf(this string data, Char c)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) ? 0 : data.Count(chk => chk == c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't want more than *one* occurrence of a particular character  in a string.  You could write an extension method to return the count of a particular character:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int CountOf(this string data, Char c)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach(Char chk in data)
        {
            if(chk == c)
               ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string email = "example@gmail.com";
string email2 = "example@gmail@gmail.com";
int c1 = email.CountOf('@'); // = 1
int c2 = email2.CountOf('@'); // = 2
```

What I really suspect you need, is email validation:

[Regex Email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/c-sharp-regex-email-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(!email.Contains("@"))
{
    // add the character
}
```

Comment: i want to prevent two characters from inserting into string.

Comment: @abazgiriabazgiri That is what this code does. `String.Contains` returns true if the string contains that character (or string). If it does not contain the character, then `String.Contains` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression...

```
if (Regex.Match(email, "@.*@")) {
    // Show error message
}
```