# Validate EMAIL in login- MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am relatively new to MVC. Would like to know how to validate a user's email address during login. For example, users who have an email address ending in "gmail.com" must be directed to a different view and other users with a different email should be directed to a different view. How should I go about doing this? Any help will be appreciated

Below is the code for my AccountController:

```html
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using _PosWorx.Models;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace _PosWorx.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        PosworxDBEntities db = new PosworxDBEntities();
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Supports");
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult SignIn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/VerifyCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
            if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/VerifyCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(VerifyCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // The following code protects for brute force attacks against the two factor codes. 
            // If a user enters incorrect codes for a specified amount of time then the user account 
            // will be locked out for a specified amount of time. 
            // You can configure the account lockout settings in IdentityConfig
            var result = await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(model.Provider, model.Code, isPersistent:  model.RememberMe, rememberBrowser: model.RememberBrowser);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(model.ReturnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid code.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);  
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
        {
            return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/SendCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var userFactors = await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(userId);
            var factorOptions = userFactors.Select(purpose => new SelectListItem { Text = purpose, Value = purpose }).ToList();
            return View(new SendCodeViewModel { Providers = factorOptions, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/SendCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(SendCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Generate the token and send it
            if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(model.SelectedProvider))
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = model.SelectedProvider, ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_userManager != null)
                {
                    _userManager.Dispose();
                    _userManager = null;
                }

                if (_signInManager != null)
                {
                    _signInManager.Dispose();
                    _signInManager = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

      

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
                : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
     
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email address validation using ASP.NET MVC data type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712043/email-address-validation-using-asp-net-mvc-data-type-attributes)

Comment: In Login use reqular expression to validate the email. Then if gmail we can mention view name like return View("GmailView") and for other email return View("OtherView"). Create Cshtml for Gmailview and Otherview. I this what you desired.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I am not sure how to go about checking the last part of the email though, how do i check if user's email matches "gmail.com". Can you please give me an idea of how to use the regular expression?

Comment: Do you me do it for you?

Comment: please mark it as answer if it help you, you can use this regex Regex.IsMatch(model.Email, @"^*@g(oogle)?mail\.com$");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you like you can use:

```
 if (model.Email.toLower().contains("@gmail.com")) 
 {
     // do something 
 }
```

in this case if the user put the string "@gmail.com" in the middle of his email address will couze a small bug :)

or this long line right here is much better:

```
if (model.Email.toLower().LastIndexOf("@gmail.com") == (model.Email.Length - 11 /* the length of "@gmail.com" + 1 */ )
{
    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this part regex part i didn't test it. But you go with similar approach

```
// Login Success Authenticate
            [HttpPost]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(model);
                }

                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        {
 // check this section
                        var isGmail = Regex.IsMatch(model.Email, @"^*@g(oogle)?mail\.com$");

                            if (isGmail)
                            {
                                return View("GmailViewCshtml", model);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                            }**
                        }
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return View(model);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (model.Email.ToLower().EndsWith("@gmail.com") && model.Email.Length > 10) 
{
    // do gmail stuff
}
```