# Can't find System.Net.Mail in VS 2010, Silverlight 5, C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am unable to add System.Net.Mail

Writing using System.Net.Mail give the error message - The namespace Mail does not exist in System.Net. Why it is searching it in System.Net when it is part of System dll

I have already added both System.Net and System references in my project

My purpose: I want to use MailAddress to validate email format. **I don't need to send any mails. Just the format validation.** For this System.Net.Mail must be added

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing client side code, Silverlight doesn't support the System.Net.Mail namespace.

Alternatively what you can do is just create a WCF service as follows.

[Send e-Mail with Silverlight](http://bronsblog.com/post/2011/07/05/Send-an-email-with-Silverlight-4.aspx)

Make use of regex to validate email address,

[Regex to validate e-Mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/c-sharp-regex-email-validation)

Comment: Thanks. That's why I am able to add System.Net.Mail in my test console application but not in the silverlight project. 
Can you please explain how else I can validate the email address format (should be simple). I'm new to coding.

Comment: Do you know about regex? make use of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/c-sharp-regex-email-validation

Answer (score 0):

There is no System.Net.Mail class for Silverlight.You can use `WCF service` which handle the sending Mails.

Here is the good `Example` http://bronsblog.com/post/2011/07/05/Send-an-email-with-Silverlight-4.aspx

and http://www.silverlightnext.com/2010/06/send-email-from-silverlight-application.html