# how to validate e - mail address

Tags: c#

i need to know how to validate e-mail address in C#.
am using a textBox to type the e-mail address and using "Submit" button to go the other form. before go to the next form it should be validate as an e-mail address.

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by validate? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself to validate the email? like regularexpressions?

Comment: use regular expressions or a loop that checks all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
public bool IsValid(string emailaddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/c-sharp-regex-email-validation you'll that this is not a good way.

Comment: didn't work 'IsValid'

Comment: @Hypenate To be fair, that's probably where they copied the answer from in the first place, not bothering to read why it's horribly wrong. ;)