# Require Regular expression to validate email address like Nitha.La.Poojari@abc.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
 public static Boolean isValidEmail(String strEmail)
    {
        bool b = Regex.IsMatch(strEmail,@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z\\u4e00-\u9fa5\\s]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
        return b;
    }
```

Above is my code which i am using to validate email.

I did not able to find regular expression for this Nitha.La.Poojari@abc.com as it contains three full stop. 
can anybody help me using regex?

Comment: Check out: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

Comment: See [Regex Email validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation)

Comment: This regex [seems to work for me](https://regex101.com/r/ecOH1i/2).  The portion before the at symbol accepts any number of dots.