# Regex should accept multiple dots but don't

Tags: regex, .net-core

I want to accept mail formats like these :

```
"x@x.com"
"x.x@x.com"
"x.x@x.com"
"x.x.x@x.com"
"x@x.x.x.com"
"x@x.x.com"
"etc..."
```

How can I modify this regex to accept dots inside emails?

```
@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"
```

thank you.

Comment: Replace `(\w){2,3}` with `\w{1,3}` or `([\w\-]+)` with `([\w.-]+)`

Comment: Don't work :/ mails like na.va.waterloo@deal.rena.com are not accepted. 
Can you post the entire regex? maybe I'm wrong with ur modifications.

Comment: [`na.va.waterloo@deal.rena.com` is matched](https://regex101.com/r/1nKgb5/1)

Comment: thank you a lot. Actually, I have onother little problem with 5 of my list of e-mails. An email like this don't match : dom.d@inter.city .. no dot at the end. How can I modify your regex to accept it?

Comment: Replace `3` with `4`.

Comment: BTW, see [Regex Email validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation)

Comment: thank you :) I don't master regex so you have done a lot for me ;)

Comment: caps@avi.trav don't work ^^ the last one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141948/discussion-between-amin89-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Use the other option - [`^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((?:\.\w{1,4})+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/1nKgb5/2)

Comment: 78 emails don't match with the last regex ^^" Damn I should learn how all this work ..

Comment: Just use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342460/3832970).  Do not bother with regex.

Comment: BTW, are you aware that TLD (last part of the domain name) can be longer than 4 characters (`.london` or `.travel`)

Comment: The last regex I can share is [`^([\w.-]+)@([\w.-]+)(\.\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/1nKgb5/3) - but now you understand how fragile the regex approach is.

Comment: it works fine thank you. What's the best approach so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342460/3832970

Comment: Probably the only one way to know, is an email valid or not is to send the email to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: when your after-@ part contains more than 1 dot, the one-char parts between the dots cannot be matched due to the `{2,3}` limiting quantifier minimum threshold. It requires at least 2 chars in between the dots.

You could fix it with [`^([\w.-]+)@([\w.-]+)(\.\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/1nKgb5/3) where all the dot parts but the last one in the domain part would appear in Group 2 and the last one will be in Group 3.

**The best approach to validate an e-mail in .NET is the [one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342460/3832970)**.