# how to check the value in the email id is correct or not?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I enter the value inside the `Textbox` and clicking the submit button the entered value should pass to the database and check whether entered text value is valid or not ..

In case entered value is correct the next `div` should be displayed..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content" style="width: 500px; margin-left: -24%;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Upload image(Max 5Mb)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <div id="showimage" runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHosEmail" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" Style="border: none;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-sucess" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #79a35a;">Start Upload</button>--%>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" Text="Submit" Style="background-color: #79a35a;" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hideimage" style="display: none;" runat="server">
                        <span>Image Name</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtimage" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Your Image Name" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileimage" runat="server" class="form-control inline v-middle input-s" />
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-sucess" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #79a35a;">Start Upload</button>--%>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" OnClick="btnupload_Click" class="btn btn-default" Text="Start Upload" Style="background-color: #79a35a;" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Onclick `"btnCheck_Click"` Value is correct the next `hideimage` `Div` should be displayed..

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CheckLogin(txtHosEmail.Text.ToString().Trim()))
        {
            showimage.Visible = false;
            hideimage.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            hideimage.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "This Email is InCorrect";
        }
    }

    protected bool CheckLogin(string Email)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Email from PadappaiCheckEmail where Email = '" + Email + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email;
        string id = "";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            id = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "" : cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation)

Comment: what do you define as "valid"?

Comment: P.S. Your SqlCommand is wrong, it never uses the parameter, as it should. `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Email from PadappaiCheckEmail where Email = @Email, con);` is the right way. Otherwise you just inject the Email value directly into the query, thus entirely defeating the point of using parameters

Comment: @kblok This Email is InCorrect

Comment: Also have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` block is the wrong way round.

```
if (!CheckLogin(txtHosEmail.Text.ToString().Trim()))
{
    showimage.Visible = false;
    hideimage.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    hideimage.Visible = true;
    lblMsg.Text = "This Email is InCorrect";
}
```

should be:

```
if (CheckLogin(txtHosEmail.Text.Trim()))
{
    showimage.Visible = false;
    hideimage.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    hideimage.Visible = true;
    lblMsg.Text = "This Email is InCorrect";
}
```

**Note the removal of `!` (and also the removal of the unnecessary `ToString()` call).**
*`CheckLogin` returns `true` if the email address is found.*

Comment: One more Suggestion <div id="hideimage" style="display: none;" runat="server">   **This code is not working

Comment: That would be a new question @VanustonIntelligence . You should create a new post for that.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things you can improve in your code.

You are calling the `ExecuteScalar` method twice

```
id = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "" : cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

You should calling that only once

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
d = result.ToString() ?? "";
```

Then you should use your SQL Parameter

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Email from PadappaiCheckEmail where Email = @Email", con);
```

And last, you should not silence your exceptions, you should remove the empty catch.