# Whats the best regex validation for email address

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to include email validation for my register form using regular expression

I've tried this code regex for validating my email

```
Dim ValidateEmail As Boolean
ValidateEmail = Regex.IsMatch(EmailAddress.Text, "^([\w]+)@([\w]+)\.([\w]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I tried to input some email in my EmailAddress. The text which is my variable name, but I got an error after putting some dot ex: jannus.domingo@yahoo.com
after Janus the dot is the error I got but after I removed dot on jannus.domingo@yahoo.com then it's fine.

Comment: I know a lot of people speak highly of regex, but it's not always the most optimal solution. In this case you'd be better off looking for the @ symbol and that it ends in a well-known top level domain like .com, .net, etc because it's really hard to capture every possible email address with regex but it's easy to know all the TLDs

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20090325234208/http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email

Comment: [Regex Email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5342375/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing about with unreadable, long, hard and unmaintainable regular expression, simply try to create an instance of the [MailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netframework-4.8) class with the string you get from the user. It will throw a [FormatException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formatexception?view=netframework-4.8) if the format is invalid.

Here's a simple example:

```vb
Function IsEmailAddressWellFormatted(ByVal address As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim address = New MailAddress(address)
        Return True
    Catch ex As FormatException
        Return False 
        ' We don't care about the actual exception here, 
        ' the fact that it's thrown is enough to know the string is not a valid format.
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)