# The correct way to validate JSON property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What is the correct way to use advance property validation when deserializing JSON to Model? I am providing the `MyClass` as an example. I need to validate Name(`required`) and Email(`e-mail address validation`). I do find only `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` to validate the required properties and nothing for e-mail validation. Unfortunately, Data Annotation validators can't be used from MVC for validation.

One idea which comes to my mind is to create custom `ContractResolver` and attach to deserializer where I could perform custom validation. Any other methods to consider?

```
public class MyClass
{
   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}

_dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(content);
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but what if you simply use `MainAddress` instead of `string` for your `Email` property? that will give you the validation for free...

Comment: @Zohar what is `MainAddress`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is MailAddress, not MainAddres. Also, I don't get how this validates? I will get an exception. Also how to validate Uri property then? It deserializes and binds perfectly with any string and throw Uri malformed exception when accessed.

Comment: Sorry, automatically typing Main everywhere... :-)

Comment: As I said, I haven't tested this yet. I'll try to find the time to do that later today.

Answer (score 1):

So I've had some time to test this, and as I suspected, `MailAddress` is deserialized to a much more complex json object than a simple address - which means that if you want to keep your json as is, you can't change the property type to `MailAddress`.

However, this doesn't mean you can't take advantage of the built in format validation it has in it's constructor, just not with auto-implemented properties.
If you change your class to this -

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string email;

   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Email { 
       get
       {
           return email;
       }
       set
       {
           var address = new MailAddress(value); 
           email = value;
       }
   }
}
```

Whenever you try to deserialize a json that contains an invalid format email address (and in fact, whenever you try to set this property to a string that's not a valid email address), you'll get a `FormatException`:

> System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass
{
   [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("email", Required = Required.Always)]
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

To validate the email you'll have to apply your own regex check after you deserialize.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to validate an email address. Instead, [use the tools the framework already provides you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356341/whats-the-best-regex-validation-for-email-address/58411056#58411056)

Comment: Sure, he'll have to apply whatever method of email validation after the deserialization anyway. Not that there's anything wrong with regex validation.