# How to use regex to capture 3 different parts from text line

Tags: c#, regex

```
" john smith (idjs) <js@email.com>"
```

How do I break the preceding into 3 parts?

```
1: john smith
2: (idjs)
3: <js@email.com>
```

I'm having trouble just trying to get any of the parts:

tried this:

```
var fullname = Regex.Match(item, $"(?=^).*(?=()").Value;
```

Comment: I would use split

Comment: Wouldn’t that split the first and last name though

Comment: split by ")" to get email. split by  "(" to get name and both sequential to get mid part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [named matched groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions) for this:

```cs
var item = " john smith (idjs) <js@email.com>";
String[] patternArr =
{
    "(?:\\s*)", 
    "(?<fullname>[a-zA-Z\\s]*?[a-zA-Z])", // captures the full name part
    "(?:\\s*)",
    "(?<idjs>\\([a-zA-Z]*\\))", // captures the idjs part
    "(?:.*)",
    "(?<email>(?:<).*@.*(?:>))" // captures the email part
};

var pattern = String.Join("", patternArr);
var m = Regex.Match(item, pattern);

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("fullname: {0}", m.Groups["fullname"]);
    Console.WriteLine("idjs: {0}", m.Groups["idjs"]);
    Console.WriteLine("email: {0}", m.Groups["email"]);
}
```

Output:

```
fullname: john smith
idjs: (idjs)
email: <js@email.com>
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y6U5j4

Comment: You beat me to the punch.  Now I need to throw away my nearly identical code.  I was, however going to suggest two things to the OP: 1) consider removing the parentheses around the `idjs` part and the angle bracket around the email during the parsing, and 2) there are much better email regexes floating around - steal one of those

Comment: how would you remove the parenthesis, desired?

Comment: @Rod To get rid of the parenthesis around the `idjs`, you can use `((?:\\()(?<idjs>[a-zA-Z]*)(?:\\)))`, and to get rid of the angle brackets around the `email` you can use `((?:<)(?<email>.*@.*)(?:>))` instead (by replacing the respective line in the `patternArr`).

Comment: By the way, I assumed that the email entries are reasonably trustworthy - hence my "naive" email regex. You can of course choose/steal a regex that fits your needs. E.g. regarding the email validation this would be a much better choice `((?:<)(?<email>\\S+@\\S+)(?:>))`. The `MailAddress` class also provides great help for easy validation of emails.
For further reading: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation) and [2](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s01.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = 
    @"\s*" +       // zero or more whitespace characters
    @"(.*)" +      // any set of one or more characters
    @"\s+" +       // one or more whitespace characters
    @"(\(.*\))" +  // zero or more characters inside parens
    @"\s" +        // a single whitespace
    @"(<.*>)"      // zero or more characters inside brackets
    ;
```

Note that `Regex.Match().Value` will not give you the parts -  only the whole string if it matches. What you want is `Regex.Match().Groups` which will return a `GroupCollection` that you can iterate over to get the parts.

```
var groups = Regex.Match(item, pattern).Groups;
foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not by using Regex, I would use split for this:

```
    var input=" john smith (idjs) <js@email.com>";

    var first=input.Split('(');
    var second=first[1].Split(')');

    var name=first[0].Trim();
    var mid=second[0].Trim();
    var email=second[1].Trim();


/*
result:
john smith
idjs
<js@email.com>
*/
```