# Why am I not getting Regex group values

Tags: c#, regex

Got some great help from this post answer a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230200/139698)

Now I'm trying take that and capture a couple patterns in my multi-line string but not working. Any hints for me?

Here's a .net [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/flM9ss) I'm playing with

```
    desired result:
    //these can be letters
      
    1: 3333  
    2: 1111
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var item = " john smith (ABCDEFG) <js@email.com>\n" + 
            "target1 = 3333, j\n" + 
            "target2 1111, ";
        String[] patternArr = {"(?:\\s*)", 
                               "(?<target1>target1 = (\\w+)])", // capture the first target
                                "(?:\\s*)", 
                               "(?<target2>target2 (\\w+))", // captures the second target
 };
        var pattern = String.Join("", patternArr);
        var m = Regex.Match(item, pattern);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("target1: {0}", m.Groups["target1"]);
            Console.WriteLine("target2: {0}", m.Groups["target2"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note `\t` in `"(?<target2>\target2 (\\w+))"` is a TAB, I think you wanted `t`. The main issue is that your regex just does not match the string like that. What are the pattern requirements? Try `var pattern = @"target1 = (?<target1>.+)\ntarget2(?<target2>.+)";`, maybe it will solve the issue.

Comment: ok, just updated OP. All I need are the 4-alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var pattern = @"target1 = (?<target1>\w+).*\ntarget2\s+(?<target2>\w+)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S3AWy2/1). *Regex details*:

- `target1 =`  - a literal string
- `(?<target1>\w+)` - Group "target1": one or more word chars
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\n` - the newline char
- `target2` - literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?<target2>\w+)` - Group "target2": one or more word chars

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/WT2T7V):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var item = " john smith (ABCDEFG) <js@email.com>\n" + 
            "target1 = 3333, j\n" + 
            "target2 1111, ";
        var pattern = @"target1 = (?<target1>\w+).*\ntarget2\s+(?<target2>\w+)";
        var m = Regex.Match(item, pattern);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("target1: {0}", m.Groups["target1"]);
            Console.WriteLine("target2: {0}", m.Groups["target2"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```cs
target1: 3333
target2: 1111
```

Comment: Also need `RegexOptions.Singeline` and remove the `\n`, that way it could be on more lines than two

Comment: @Charlieface If it were, I would mention. The lines are consecutive in the original input.

Comment: I noticed if I swap targets in the item value the match doesn't occur. Can you please help me understand how the order is important? What if I didn't know which one comes first? https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RGV6a

Comment: @Rod It is evident, isn't it? Look, if you have a pattern like `a b` and a string `b a`, there is just no match. The `a b` pattern matches only `a b`. A possible solution will look like [this](https://ideone.com/RzaNpd).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is it suppose to work here at regex101  https://regex101.com/r/qIyYCV/1

Comment: @Rod Sure, just give it the *plain text*: https://regex101.com/r/qIyYCV/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure I understand why my version didn't work, would you mind sharing more insight? sorry.

Comment: @Rod you are using a string literal at regex101.com, while you should be using *plain text*. Please familiarize with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636208/3832970).