# RegEx for email so that it fails if the email does not have at least 1 letter somewhere before the @

Tags: c#, regex

I have tried to find a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation) but without luck.
I have written these 2 RegExes for email validation which pretty meet almost all of my criteria.

**RegEx 1**

```
^\w?[A-Za-z]{1}\w?@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,}){0,1}$
```

**RegEx 2**

```
[\w\.\-]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,}(\.[a-z]{2,}){0,1}$
```

But they do not solve 1 critical issue.
I want the RegEx to fail when matched with something like:
_@gmail.com
_**@gmail.com

*8**@gmail.com

8@gmail.com

88@gmail.com

8*@gmail.com

**So basically I want the email to have at least 1 lower or upper case letter and it does not matter it is at the beginning , middle or end of the email itself(before the @).**

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
^[^\s@]*[A-Za-z][^\s@]*@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s@]*` Match optional chars other than @ or a whitespace char
- `[A-Za-z]`
- `[^\s@]*` Match optional chars other than @ or a whitespace char
- `@` Match literally
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char
- `\.[a-z]{2,}` Match `.` and 2 or more chars a-z
- `$` End of string

See a [.NET regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/b5Gv5c/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could use positive look ahead to do this.
`(?=.*[a-z])` for lowercase
`(?=.*[A-Z])` for uppercase

So something like this should do the trick:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^@ \t\r\n]+@[^@ \t\r\n]+\.[^@ \t\r\n]+
```

I let you customize the filter after the @ as you seem to have specific needs.